# Logging based on levels on log4j in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Below is the log4j properties and the Java code. All the logs are getting logged only in Debug. I even tried with adding Threshold, no luck yet. I need to log the log statements in a separate file based on log levels.

All the logs are getting logged only in debug log file, and if I remove debug log, then it is getting logged in info log file.

Giving Threshold option also doesn't work.

```
log4j.rootLogger = OFF

#define the console appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# now define the layout for the appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# now define the rollingFIle appender
log4j.category.com=error, myErrorappender
log4j.additivity.com=false
log4j.appender.myErrorappender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myErrorappender.File=/Users/uthaman/Documents/workspace/Logging/myErrorlog.log
log4j.appender.myErrorappender.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.myErrorappender.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.myErrorappender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myErrorappender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c (%F:%L) - %m%n


log4j.category.com=info,myInfoappender
log4j.additivity.com=false
log4j.appender.myInfoappender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myInfoappender.File=/Users/user/Documents/workspace/Logging/myInfolog.log
log4j.appender.myInfoappender.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.myInfoappender.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.myInfoappender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myInfoappender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.category.com=debug,myDebugappender
log4j.additivity.com=false
log4j.appender.myDebugappender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myDebugappender.File=/Users/user/Documents/workspace/Logging/myDebuglog.log
log4j.appender.myDebugappender.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.myDebugappender.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.myDebugappender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myDebugappender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

This is the java code where the log statements are logged:

```
public class Logging {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logging.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.error("This is error");
        logger.info("This is info");
        logger.debug("This is debug");
    }

}
```

Comment: `log4j.rootLogger = OFF` - it states `The OFF Level has the highest possible rank and is intended to turn off logging.` It should not log actually.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `log4j.xml` configuration instead of the `log4j.properties`. The following configuration (a basic one) works as desired...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="log.info" />
        <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="threshold" value="info"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %C{6} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppenderDebug" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="log.debug" />
        <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %C{6} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppenderError" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="log.error" />
        <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="threshold" value="error"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %C{6} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderDebug" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderError" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: THRESHOLD parameter doesn't log only the specified log level, it logs the levels below that as well, is there a way to strictly restrict from the log level to be logged.

Comment: <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
            <param name="LevelToMatch" value="error"/> 
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/> 
        </filter>     
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

You have defined duplicate key in the log4j configuration:

```
    log4j.category.com=error, myErrorappender
    log4j.additivity.com=false

    log4j.category.com=info,myInfoappender
    log4j.additivity.com=false

    log4j.category.com=debug,myDebugappender
    log4j.additivity.com=false
```

- Log4j **only** use the last one which is the debug appender ---> "All the logs are getting logged only in debug log file"
- When you remove the debug appender, info appender will be the last one ---> " if I remove debug log, then it is getting logged in info log file."

**Solution:**

```
    log4j.category.com=debug,myDebugappender,myInfoappender,myErrorappender
    log4j.additivity.com=false
    log4j.appender.myDebugappender.Threshold=DEBUG
    log4j.appender.myInfoappender.Threshold=INFO
    log4j.appender.myErrorappender.Threshold=ERROR
```

If you  must filter events by exact level match:

```
     log4j.appender.myDebugappender.filter=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
     log4j.appender.myDebugappender.filter.levelToMatch=DEBUG
     ...
```

Comment: After changing this, i'm seeing the logs in all 3 logs, but the problem is, Debug file is getting DEBUG, INFO and ERROR logs as well. INFO file is getting INFO and ERROR logs as well. how to restrict that.

Comment: Is there a way to strictly restrict to log only the defined log levels to a log file?

Comment: "If you must filter events by exact level match, then you can attach a LevelMatchFilter to any appender to filter out logging events by exact level match."[http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a2.9](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a2.9)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `filter` in your configuration file to specify a `specific level` to written written to the `appender` . Please the sample code attached

```
    <appender name="DEBUG" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
            </layout>
            <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
                    <param name="levelMin" value="DEBUG" />
                    <param name="levelMax" value="DEBUG" />
            </filter>
    </appender>
```